# Discord.py how to mention/show username of someone who used the command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, mention

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaZh7.png
Discord.py how to mention/show the username of someone who used the command?
As you can see in the image it says "you cleared ... messages".
I want it to say "@Jonathan#9999" or "Jonathan" cleared ... messages. how do I do it? how do I mention someone that used the command?

Example of what I want - https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4HNp.png.

What it does now - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaZh7.png.

--That's my code--

```
@client.command(name='clear')
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=5,):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    Embed = discord.Embed(title = '✅ Success!', description=f'cleared {amount} messages!', color = 0x00ff00)
    await ctx.message.channel.send(embed=Embed)
```

Comment: `ctx.author.name`. Please do not post images nor links as code, the code should be in the question itself

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Thanks for replying where do I add it? I'm new to discord.py

Comment: Where do you think you should add it? It's a pretty straightforward answer...

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński...

Comment: Put it where you want it to be...

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I tried putting it in description=f'{ctx.author.name} cleared {amount} messages!' but it didn't work... so I thought maybe I am using the code in the wrong location

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? What exactly happens?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Nvm thank you it worked I accidently mistyped the command

Answer (score 1):

```
@client.command(name='clear')
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=5,):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        Embed = discord.Embed(title = '✅ Success!', 
        description=f'{ctx.author.mention} cleared {amount} messages!', color = 0x00ff00)
        await ctx.message.channel.send(embed=Embed)
```

I've tested the code, it's working :)

[image: Example]